# any short way for (a == 0 || a == foo) in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I'm writing some code like this in Ruby:

```
if very_long_variable_name_that_cant_be_shortened == 0 || very_long_variable_name_that_cant_be_shortened == foo
```

it's obviously long, and it dosen't look really good. Is there any way to write this shorter?

thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked `include?` ?

Comment: Do we assume that `very_long_variable_name` is a `Hash`?

Comment: How about creating a local variable?

Comment: Yes, but it would be nicer if there was a way to write this somewhat like `long_variable_name == (0 || foo)`. Thanks.

Comment: @PNY No, I just meant a really long variable name, not especially `Hash`es. sorry to be confusing, I'll edit my question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may want to use [`include?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Array.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
>> [0, foo].include? very_long_variable_name_that_cant_be_shortened
=> true
```

Answer (score 4):

```
case very_long_variable_name_that_cant_be_shortened
when 0, foo
  ...
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
def helperMethd (f):
    return foo == 0 || f == foo; 

if helperMethd(very_long_variable_name_that_cant_be_shortened):
   bla bla
```